# PTIJ: Which came first, Mesechtas Beitza or Chullin?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Just as bad as the chicken/egg dilemma, I'd like to know which Gemara was composed first, Mesechtas Beitza/Beiah, or Chullin? Just because Beitza precedes Chullin by a ton of volumes doesn't mean Chullin wasn't finished first.

On the one hand, Beitza, which is part of ***Moed***, precedes Chullin, which is part of ***Kodashim***.

On the other hand, Chullin comes before Beitza in terms of its own volumes (Chullin is the ***third*** Mesechta of Kodashim, while Beitza is the ***eighth*** Masechta of Moed).

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Berachos 41b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.41b.4-5), Chullin came first.

> רַב חִסְדָּא וְרַב הַמְנוּנָא הֲווֹ יָתְבִי בִּסְעוֹדְתָּא. אַיְיתוֹ לְקַמַּיְיהוּ תַּמְרֵי וְרִמּוֹנֵי. שְׁקַל רַב הַמְנוּנָא, בָּרֵיךְ אַתַּמְרֵי בְּרֵישָׁא. אֲמַר לֵיהּ רַב חִסְדָּא: לָא סָבַר לַהּ מָר לְהָא דְּאָמַר רַב יוֹסֵף, וְאִיתֵּימָא רַבִּי יִצְחָק: כׇּל הַמּוּקְדָּם בְּפָסוּק זֶה קוֹדֵם לִבְרָכָה? אֲמַר לֵיהּ: זֶה שֵׁנִי לְ״אֶרֶץ״, וְזֶה חֲמִישִׁי לְ״אֶרֶץ״. אֲמַר לֵיהּ: מַאן יָהֵיב לַן נִגְרֵי דְפַרְזְלָא וּנְשַׁמְּעִינָּךְ.
>
> Rav Chisda and Rav Hamnuna were sitting at a meal. They brought before them dates and pomegranates. Rav Hamnuna took and blessed on the dates first. Rav Chisda said to him, "Does the master not hold of that which Rav Yosef, and some say Rebbi Yitzchak, said, 'all which precedes in this passuk precedes for the blessing'?" He said to him, "This is second to its 'land,' and this is fifth to its 'land.'" He said to him, "Who would give us iron legs that we may serve you!"

We see from here that even if one item comes first in a general unit, as pomegranates precede dates in the passuk, we still grant precedence to the later one if it comes earlier in its subunit. So, too, Chullin, which is third to its Seder, precedes Beitza, which is eighth to its Seder.

Answer (score 1):

We must always go up in holiness (see Megillah 9b; Menachos 99b).

The profane laws of eggs are taught in Chulin (64b), while the holier laws of the egg which hatched while on holiday, are discussed in Beitzah (2b). Thus, Chulin came first.

It is also very important not to mince words when discussing eggs. I hear many people say ‘like any egg’ or ‘about an eggs-worth’.
Exactness in this discussion is very important, as we learn in Tosefta (Yevamos 10:3, ed. Zuck.; cf. Bechoros 7:5):

> א"ר ישמעאל בר' יוחנן בן ברוקה שמעתי בכרם ביבנה מי שאין לו אלא ביצה אחת הרי הוא סריס
>
> Rebbi Yishmeal son 0f Rebbi Yochanan Ben Bereka said: I hear in the vineyard by Yavnah that anyone who does not have one egg is a Sris.

Sris, meaning Rabbi from Esther (7:9) אחד מן הסריסים, which is translated in the Targum as חד מן רבניא, meaning Rabbi.

Thus the difference in “k’beitzah” and an actual beitzah may be the difference between being an ordained rabbi and just a simpleton.

This matters when it comes to rulings, especially concerning eggs. It would seem that the Rabbi with the egg (certainly not his only form of certification) is far more reliable. You may even attain the name ‘Egg Rabbi’ (אגרב, see Bechoros 41a).